# How to run Application Client on the GlassFish Server 4 from command line

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, ejb, client

I just started to learn EJB and I wrote a simple bean and client application. Below is a code:

Interface:

```
package ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface MySessionRemote {

   String getResult();
}
```

Bean:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class MySession implements MySessionRemote {

  // @EJB
  //private static MySessionRemote mySession1;

  @Override
  public String getResult() {
    return "Bean";
  }
}
```

Client application:

```
package entappclient;
import javax.naming.*;
import ejb.MySessionRemote;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

public class Main {
  // @EJB private static MySessionRemote mySession;


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    new Main().Save();
 }
 public Context getContext() throws javax.naming.NamingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", 
                "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");

    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", 
                "com.sun.enterprise.naming");

    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
                "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");

    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");

    return new InitialContext(props);

 }
 public void Save () {

    //System.out.println(mySession1.getResult());
    try {

        Context jndiContext = getContext(); 
        System.out.println("0");

        MySessionRemote ref = ySessionRemote)jndiContext.lookup("java:global/EntAppEJB-  ejb/MySession!ejb.MySessionRemote");

        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println(ref.getResult());

    } catch (Exception e ) {
        System.out.println("Save"+e);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run it under NetBeans 8 everything works fine. The result is:

0

1

Bean

But when I try to run this from command line using : appclient - client *path*/EntAppClient.jar, it does not work. The result is:

0

```
Savejavax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/EntAppEJB-ejb/M
ySession!ejb.MySessionRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initia
l=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHo
st=localhost, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.J
NDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Ro
ot exception is javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remot
e business interfaceejb.MySessionRemote [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFou
ndException: ejb.MySessionRemote]]
```

Can anybody help me to find out why I can run this under NetBeans but it does not work from command line.

Best regards

Marcin

Comment: Looks like `MySessionRemote` is not in the classpath of the client. How are you packaging your client?

Comment: Yes. MySessionRemote interface was not in the client's classpath. Thanks for giving me a hint. Now it works.